# How do I change java's timezone?

Tags: java, timezone

There is something wrong with my linux desktop's timezone and its getting changed to "London" sometimes. I have now manually changed it to "Los Angeles/Pacific". But when I run a java program, the timezone is still set to "Europe/London". How do I change it to the Pacific timezone once so that it takes effect for all subsequent programs?

Running "date" shows the following:
$date
Thu Jul 18 15:27:26 PDT 2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the time zone of a specific date instance. By using:

```
date.setTimeZone(TimeZone value)
```

In order to create a time zone instance and modify the time zone if needed use:

```
TimeZone timeZone = new TimeZone ();
timeZone.setRawOffset(int offsetMillis);
```

Better approch is to solve it at the OS level.
Use this commands:

```
# sudo cp /etc/localtime /etc/localtime.dist
# sudo ln -fs /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles /etc/localtime
```

Comment: @BrianRoach The title say explicitly how to change java timezone.